# Is GZIP working always (invisible), by default?

Tags: gzip, task-management

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

I want to know if the app GZIP is working, invisible, at any time, by default, even if we don't ask it to do something.

In other words... Can this app work in an automatic way, out of our control? ???

My question is related to the fact I discovered some HDD activity not requested by me and, when I use the Task Manager to see which one was working, I found GZIP app works, doing... I don't know what!

Of course, it wasn't the only one App working, at that time, but...

If GZIP can work automatically... Is there a way to turn it off? Can we disable it? ???

Comment: *"working, invisible, at any time, by default"* it's used by `logrotate` to compress and archive system logs - perhaps that's what you observed?

Comment: I'm not sure. But, if this was the case... Can we uninstall  or set-off that "logrotate" app?